# Fourier-Analysis of Stationary Random Signals

Tags: fourier-transform, dft, random-process, stationary

Let's say we have discrete-time stationary random signals with Gaussian PDF of mean value 0 and variance 1, whose individual signal values are uncorrelated.

For such a signal, how can we determine ACF and the PSD?

Answer (score 1):

assuming ergodicity...

ACF:

$$\begin{align}
R_x[k] &= \lim_{N \to \infty} \tfrac{1}{2N+1} \sum\limits_{n=-N}^{N} x[n] \, x[n+k] \\
  &= \mathbb{E}\Big\{ x[n] \, x[n+k]  \Big\} \\
  &= \sigma_x^2 \ \delta[k] \\
  &= 1\  \delta[k] \\
\end{align}$$

PSD:

$$ S_x(e^{j\omega}) = \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} R_x[n] \, e^{-j \omega n} $$

Comment: Why assuming ergodicity?

Comment: i guess it's not an assumption, but an implication of a stationary process.  it means that the averaging done in time (which is the top equation) can be replaced with a probabilistic averaging of the same quantity (which is the expectation).

Answer (score 1):

You have described a discrete-time [Gaussian white noise](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/278277/143817) to a T.

For a white stationary Gaussian random process $n[k]$, the autocorrelation $R_n[k]$ is:
$$
R_n[k] = \mathbb E \left( n[m]n[m+k] \right) = \sigma^2 \delta[k],
$$
where $\sigma^2$ is the variance.

The power spectral density $P(\omega)$ is just the DTFT of the autocorrelation, which is:
$$
P(\omega) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty R_n[k] e^{j\omega k} = \sigma^2
$$
i.e., it is the same for all frequencies ("white noise").

Comment: it's bandlimited white noise.  bandlimited to the Nyquist frequency.

Comment: remember *"true"* white noise has infinite bandwidth and, as a result, infinite power.  but power is variance (if the mean is zero), which is not infinite.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson That's assuming it is interpreted as a continuous-time signal. In the DTFT domain it is not band-limited because the DTFT is $2\pi$-periodic

Comment: that's true, but the variance is finite and you do not integrate the PSD from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ to get the power with a discrete-time random signal (or any discrete-time signal).  you integrate from $-\pi$ to $+\pi$.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson The assumption of integrating from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ to compute power is not contained or implied anywhere in this answer

Comment: true.  but i would continue to call it *"**bandlimited** white noise"*.  just as you can use a sinc function to interpolate between samples of $x[n]$, you can use a sinc function to interpolate between $R_x[k]$.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson I think that's a matter of taste. I prefer to think of the discrete-time word as being abstract, self-contained, and pure, independent of the ugly, dirty, cruel, analog world

Comment: okay.  but unless this remains in the mind of the computer, eventually that white noise is coming out into the ugly, dirty, cruel, analog world.  and it won't be white anymore, because white noise in the ugly, dirty, cruel, analog world has infinite power.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson fair, but homework-esque problems like this usually stay inside the safety of computerland :)

Comment: you guys make me feel like cozying up under a nice warm blanket with a nice cold beer and reading an Algebra book, which should shield me  from the ugly, dirty, cruel analog world well enough.

Comment: @MarcusMüller are we talking about [Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_algebra) or (*deep voice*) [Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_algebra)?

Comment: @CarlosDanger I'm thinking of (*extremely deep voice*) [Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number_theory). Essentially, I want to feel closer to the channel codes I use.

Comment: @MarcusMüller your profile picture takes on new meaning now

Comment: @CarlosDanger that? It's just my personal letter head logo that I've designed a couple of years ago; I'm in the business of SDR, so having a series of sincs and a couple of elements of $\mathrm{GF}(2)$ just seemed natural :)